# How to create a swagger documentation for a wordpress custom endpoints which is inside a custom plugin?

Tags: wordpress, swagger, swagger-ui

My site is a wordpress site. I need to create some custom endpoints as routes in a custom wordpress plugin. I need to write this custom plugin from scratch.. After writing this custom endpoints.. I want to document these custom endpoints routes with swagger.. Could you please tell me some ways to achieve this..

Comment: This should do : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-swaggerui/

Comment: Thank you Bhanu... I think that this plug-in only creates documentation for http://your site.com/wp-json/ and not for the endpoints that we create in our custom plug-in.. right? Could you please clarify...